# Is Red Dead Redemption multiplayer region locked?

Tags: region-lock, red-dead-redemption

I have an american PS3.
I bought the UK version of Red Dead Redemption.
I am currently living in Italy
I tried to play a multiplayer match with a friend with an american PS3 and american RDD. He is currently living in the US.
Everytime we invited each other an error prompt with no explanation whatsoever appeared.

I was wondering if we couldn't play a multiplayer session game because: 
A. our discs being from different regions? 
B. or us being in different countries? 
C. a combination of A and B.

Does anyone here know something about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I have experienced, RDR multiplayer is not region-locked. I live in the Netherlands and have a European Xbox 360. I've played multiplayer games several times with my friends who live in the US. What kind of error prompt did you receive?

Have both of you updated your games to the latest versions? There have been at least 2 patches since release that fixed some multiplayer connection issues.

Comment: We were playing the updated versions.

Comment: You are right ... I was able to play with my friend after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Red Dead connects to a central server to start up the game, then they may simply not allow you because the ping is too high.

I know that Modern Warfare 2 often refuses to connect due to pings above 100 ms.